# Conversion type error when chaining method

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm lost on this piece of c++ code that involves iterating over a list contained in a struct `RouteInfo`. How come the code shows this compilation error: `Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_List_simple_types<int>, std::_List_iter_types<int, size_t, ptrdiff_t, int *, const int *, int &, const int &, std::_List_node<int, void *> *>>>>" to "std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_List_simple_types<int>, std::_List_iter_types<int, size_t, ptrdiff_t, int *, const int *, int &, const int &, std::_List_node<int, void *> *>>>>" ...`

Problem code

```
void iterateOverListInStruct(std::multimap<RouteInfo, int> aMap)
{
    std::multimap<RouteInfo, int /* vehicle id */>::iterator it = aMap.begin();
    for (; it != aMap.end(); it++)
    {
        std::list<int>::iterator itr = it->first.secList.begin();
    }
}
```

and this code doesn't show any compiler errors?

```
void iterateOverListInStruct(std::multimap<RouteInfo, int> aMap)
{
    std::multimap<RouteInfo, int /* vehicle id */>::iterator it = aMap.begin();
    for (; it != aMap.end(); it++)
    {
        std::list<int> list = it->first.secList;
        std::list<int>::iteartor itr = list.begin();
    }
}
```

Here is the class `RouteInfo`:

```
class RouteInfo{
    public:
        list<int>secList;}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You may find the raw error messages given on the Output tab more complete and easier to wrangle into text that the errors as presented on the Error List tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value_type` of `std::multimap` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`, so `it->first.secList` is `const std::list<int>`, and `begin()` on it returns `std::list<int>::const_iterator`

Your second example copies it into new non-const `std::list<int>` and iterator type  returned by `begin()` is then `std::list<int>::iterator`

To fix the error change `itr` type to `std::list<int>::const_iterator`